# Given $f(x,y) = 8xy$, for $0<x<y<1$, find $P(X+Y > 1)$

Tags: probability, statistics

Could anyone help me with this probability question?

[Question Picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dT88V.png)

Its not homework, its more of a question from a past year paper that I'm doing for self revision.

What I did was:

$P(X+Y > 1) = P(Y > 1 - X)$

1) Draw the graph for $y$ and $x$.

[Graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gN2Bo.png)

So have to evaluate the area in the graph,
$$
\int_{0}^{1}\int_{1-x}^{1} 8xy\,dydx
$$

Integrating this. i... dont know how to integrate this. However, the answer is 5/6...

I think it has to do with the range, but im not sure how to proceed. Can anyone assist? :D

Thanks guys!

EDIT: Realized i shaded wrongly, new uploaded.

Comment: Realized I shaded it wrongly, Thank you! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, observe that the problem provides the condition $y>x$.  More precisely, if you ignore this condition and and just think of the domain as the unit square, you get that the probability is
$$
\int_0^1\int_0^18xydydx=2,
$$
which should be $1$.

On the other hand, if you use the condition that $y>x$, you have the integral over the region is
$$
\int_0^1\int_x^18xydydx=1,
$$
as desired.

Therefore, for your problem, you need the probability that $X+Y>1$, but recall the condition that $Y>X$.  Therefore, we need both $Y>X$ and $Y>1-X$.  When $X<\frac{1}{2}$, the second condition is more restrictive and when $X>\frac{1}{2}$, the first condition is the restrictive one.  Therefore your probability should be divided at $x=\frac{1}{2}$:
$$
\int_0^{\frac{1}{2}}\int_{1-x}^18xydydx+\int_{\frac{1}{2}}^1\int_x^18xydydx=\frac{13}{48}+\frac{9}{16}=\frac{5}{6}.
$$

Comment: I see now! Thank you so much for your help! :) I find it difficult to see the ranges i should integrate given the restrictions of the conditions, is there any way I can more easily see it? I normally look at the graph and try to discern the ranges.

Comment: Not really, graphing is a good way to figure out what's going on.  One algebraic way to figure this out is to write all the inequalities that pertain, in this case $Y>X$ and $Y>1-X$ and solve $X=1-X$ to find the intersection points to determine which inequality is more restrictive at each case.